# webdriveragentrunner iphoneos12.2-arm64.xctestrun doesn't exist

Tags: ios, xcode, appium

I want to automate ios app using appium.
The thing is that I am getting this error when I use appium inspector in order to open my installed application for the first time:
xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65"

[image: xcodebuild-failed]

I followed different solutions I found online (like enable automatically manage signings in webdriveragent project, code signing identity...) but I am still getting this error.
Seems that this path does't exist in my computer. 
Is there a way to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to walk through [Appium XCUITest Driver Real Device Setup](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest-real-devices/) article and perhaps [Real device security settings](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver#real-device-security-settings) chapter of the [`appium-xcuitest-driver`](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver#real-device-security-settings) documentation.

Most probably you have wrong [XCode configuration with regards to signing mobile application packages](https://ioscodesigning.com/generating-code-signing-files/)

The easiest option would be considering using [Appium Studio](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/) which has a simple wizard allowing [creation of iOS provisioning profile](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/AS+-+Creating+a+provision+profile) in few clicks.

Comment: I follow those steps but still face this issue. I don't have the path that mentioned in the error (Build/Products...). Is there a way to install WebDriverAgentRunner?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to use one command from [Full manual configuration](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest-real-devices/)

Steps that I made:

1. install appium:
   npm install -g appium
2. Successfully build webDriverAgentRunner from xcode.
3. cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent

**xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination 'id=<id_of_your_device>' test**

**Don't kill the console**

4. [Open appium desktop and try to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2DFC.png)